result.getExtra() not showing mailto:
This is Java code from my project in Android Studio:
webView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
    WebView.HitTestResult result = webView.getHitTestResult();

    Log.d("find_mailto", result.getExtra());

    return true;
});

When I click on a link like https://www.example.com I see the full string in Logcat but when I click on a linked e-mail address like mailto:info@example.com console only shows info@example.com. For some reason mailto: is missing.
Why doesn't result.getExtra() include mailto:?
How can I check if the pressed link is a linked e-mail? (I don't want e.g. check if it contains @ in it.)
BTW: It's same for tel:.

Seems like Android simply removes mailto: and therefore I cannot check for it.
I endend up using getType() to detect e-mail addresses like this:
    if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.EMAIL_TYPE) {
        // Do something
    }

